# ValueError: could not convert string to float in jupyter for .txt file saved from matlab

Tags: python, numpy

I have some .txt file which is saved from Matlab. I want to load them in Jupiter. But, when I've used the

```
np.loadtxt(r'C:...\data.txt')
```

It gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-1.3223e-24,-34.367,36.531,40.284,41.264
```

Can you help me to solve this? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `delimiter` parameter:

```
np.loadtxt(r'C:...\data.txt', delimiter=",")
```